# It is possible to access Storage type variables from other smart contracts?

Tags: storage, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to develop an application to track a supply chain, but due to the chain having several actors, the functionality of the main contract has extended beyond the 25kb limit.

So I'm splitting the functionality of the contract into several contracts, and I have a question about whether it is possible to access Storage type variables from other contracts. If possible, could you give me a clue, since I have not found information about it?

Answer (score 3):

You can **read** storage properties if they have a `public` [visibility modifier](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters).

You can also create a corresponding setter functions. Mind that this example implementation allows anyone to set the number, so you should add an authorization mechanism so that only some senders can set the values.

```
// deployed on 0x123
contract A {
    uint256 public number;

    function setNumber(uint256 _number) external {
        number = _number;
    }
}
```

```
// deployed on 0x456
contract B {
    function getNumberInA() external view returns (uint256) {
        return A(0x123).number();
    }
    
}
```

---

If you're open to experimental features, you can also use the Diamond pattern ([EIP-2535](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2535), currently not approved yet) to make use of the common storage of the proxy contract, and implementation deployed on multiple addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a question on the example you gave, in contract B it is supposed that I should get the same number as established on contract A?, because I have replicated your example on Remix and on the line `return A(0x123).number();` I copied the tx hash but I did't have the same number as in contract A. It gets the global scope number value, but I require the local scope, that is the number value after passed by the function.

Comment: @NathaliaBarreiros Yes, it's expected to return the storage property (called global scope in your comment) value - not the function variable (local scope) value. This way you can only access `public` storage properties of other contracts, but there's no way to access function variables of other contracts deployed on different addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to have a Base contract and then create subcontracts. So your Base contract will access subcontracts' functions and variables. You have to implement `inheritance`. Let's say you have Base and Sub contracts;

```
// with this import you will have access to contract Name inside Sub.sol file
import "./Sub.sol"

contract Base is Sub{
   // here you can just refence storage variables inside Sub.sol
   // BUT storage variables inside Sub.sol has to be  "public"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, EIP2535 Diamonds solves the 24kb size limit. It does this not by accessing state variables from other contracts but by storing all state variables in one contract but utilizing code from other contracts. An into article about it is here: https://eip2535diamonds.substack.com/p/introduction-to-the-diamond-standard

EIP2535 Diamonds is beyond experimental technology. There are deployed diamonds holding millions of dollars of assets on Ethereum and Polygon. More than 30 projects are using it as this point.

Answer (score 0):

Smart contracts can't access storage from each other directly. Instead, they exchange data through function calls. However, as you mentioned, there is a limit to the amount of code that can be deployed to the blockchain (24 kB).

One possible solution, suggested by Nick Mudge on [EIP-2535](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2535), is to have a proxy contract called "diamond" that delegates function calls to their appropriate implementation contracts called "facets". The 24 kB size limit issue is resolved, since you can have an arbitrarily large number of facets. Furthermore, and all the facets of a diamond share the same storage context, which eliminates the need for function calls between themselves.

The specification is very robust and powerful. In particular, [Cartesi](https://cartesi.io/) has been using Diamonds to expand the functionality of smart contracts beyond the usual limit, and taking advantage of the shared storage context to reduce the gas costs of function calls. If you wish to read more about EIP-2535 and its implications on code and storage upgradability, feel free to read my [article](https://medium.com/cartesi/upgrading-smart-contract-code-and-storage-layout-with-eip-2535-diamonds-31e0aff5d255) on Medium.